# Generalized linear model (GLM) for ordinal data- Matlab

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, matlab, ordinal-data

I have data collected in a survey from different subjects. 
the survey was based in Likert scale and as result the collected data is ordinal data(it is 7 category ordinal data)

I want to determine the effect of different regressor parameters with the help of the generalized linear model (GLM) and by Using MATLAB.

My independent variables are the participant's age, gender, and familiarity with the asked question topic.

so my question is which link function I should use for ordinal data ( I want to run code in MATLAB with the help of its built in function glmfit)

Comment: Even with just two questions a) This is one question too many and b) Your second question, about Matlab, is off topic.

Comment: @ Peter Flom i edit my question, I hope the problem was solved